# Install module on Spyder

Tags: python, spyder

i am trying to install a quandl module on spyder standalone version.

I tried to run the *!pip install quandl* command on the iPhyton console, but I receive this output

```
Python path configuration:
  PYTHONHOME = '/Applications/Spyder.app/Contents/Resources'
  PYTHONPATH = (not set)
  program name = '/Users/gianluca/miniconda3/bin/python'
  isolated = 0
  environment = 1
  user site = 1
  safe_path = 0
  import site = 1
  is in build tree = 0
  stdlib dir = '/Applications/Spyder.app/Contents/Resources/lib/python3.11'
  sys._base_executable = '/Users/gianluca/miniconda3/bin/python'
  sys.base_prefix = '/Applications/Spyder.app/Contents/Resources'
  sys.base_exec_prefix = '/Applications/Spyder.app/Contents/Resources'
  sys.platlibdir = 'lib'
  sys.executable = '/Users/gianluca/miniconda3/bin/python'
  sys.prefix = '/Applications/Spyder.app/Contents/Resources'
  sys.exec_prefix = '/Applications/Spyder.app/Contents/Resources'
  sys.path = [
    '/Applications/Spyder.app/Contents/Resources/lib/python311.zip',
    '/Applications/Spyder.app/Contents/Resources/lib/python3.11',
    '/Applications/Spyder.app/Contents/Resources/lib/python3.11/lib-dynload',
  ]
Fatal Python error: init_fs_encoding: failed to get the Python codec of the filesystem encoding
Python runtime state: core initialized
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'encodings'

Current thread 0x00000001de7b5000 (most recent call first):
  <no Python frame>
```

I also tried to install module directly from my MAC terminal (pip install quandl) and everything was fine, but I think I've installed the module on a different python interpreter because if I try to import module on Spyder it doesn't work. I also tried to change the interpreter on Spyder, but I receive this message on the iPhyton console

```
An error ocurred while starting the kernel
The Python environment or installation whose interpreter is located at
    /Users/gianluca/miniconda3/bin/python
doesn't have the spyder‑kernels module or the right version of it installed (>= 2.5.0 and < 2.6.0). Without this module is not possible for Spyder to create a console for you.

You can install it by activating your environment first (if necessary) and then running in a system terminal:
    conda install spyder-kernels=2.5
or
    pip install spyder-kernels==2.5.*
```

So I tried to run the command conda install spyder-kernels=2.5 on the terminal but I see this message

```
Retrieving notices: ...working... done
Channels:
 - defaults
Platform: osx-arm64
Collecting package metadata (repodata.json): done
Solving environment: failed

PackagesNotFoundError: The following packages are not available from current channels:

  - spyder-kernels=2.5*

Current channels:

  - defaults

To search for alternate channels that may provide the conda package you're
looking for, navigate to

    https://anaconda.org

and use the search bar at the top of the page.
```

Anyone know what I have to do in order to finally install that module on my Spyder?
Thanks for helping me :)

Comment: The first message shows the `encodings` library is not installed.  Have you tried installing that, by chance?

Answer (score 0):

I think what you want to do is install `quandl` in your Anaconda environment.

For context, you wouldn't install a Python package "in Spyder"; Spyder is an IDE written in Python and is central to the Anaconda Python distribution environment. To do most things, you would need a Python installation with spyder, numpy, matplotlib etc... these are all different Python packages. Anaconda simply provides a distribution and package management system for those who don't want to hack around in terminals/consoles when they have to build/compile something.

You can find instructions on installing packages here:
https://docs.conda.io/projects/conda/en/latest/user-guide/concepts/installing-with-conda.html

`conda` is the "package manager" for Anaconda. What you want to do is try to launch an Anaconda console, where you will be in the environment that contains your Spyder package (and other Python packages) and do the `conda install quandl` command.

Note that you may need to enable a different Anaconda repository (like conda-forge) that has the `quandl` package.

Comment: I believe a standalone install of Spyder effectively sets up it's own virtual environment when it is installed and activates this when executed. That looks like it exists in the same place that the Python interpreter exists - in your case here: `sys.executable = '/Users/gianluca/miniconda3/bin/python'`.

You'd have to figure out how to activate that environment and do the install (with either `pip` or `conda` depending on how the standalone Spyder environment is managed).

An easier solution is to set up your own `conda` environment, and install `spyder`, `quandl` and anything else neeeded